# Get index of element clicked compared to all this type of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following HTML structure:

```html
<div id="people-container">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="col-xs-4 people">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 people">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 people">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="col-xs-4 people">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 people">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 people">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="col-xs-4 people">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 people">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 people">
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

As you can see I have 9 people divs. I want to be able on the click of each of them, to tell which one of the 9 was clicked.

I can get their index, but it will return a value {0, 1, 2}, I also can get their parents index, but the same range, {0, 1, 2}.
I thought about multiplying the parents index with it's own index, but of course it doesn't work, max value would be 4, and most of the values would be 0...

I also don't want to make 9 if conditions. Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this you can use `index()` passing a selector to group the required elements together. Try this:

```js
$('.people').click(function() {
  console.log($(this).index('.people'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="people-container">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="col-xs-4 people">people</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 people">people</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 people">people</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="col-xs-4 people">people</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 people">people</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 people">people</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="col-xs-4 people">people</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 people">people</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 people">people</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Store the clicked `div` and its parent's index in separate variables. The index for current `div` can be accessed by the following formula:

```
var currentIndex = 3 * parentIndex + clickedIndex;
```

Comment: Yeah... simple math. Haven't thought about it! Thanks

Comment: This is a nice solution, but a little rigid if the number of `.people` elements per container changes.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan True. The workaround in JS would be uglier than the simplistic jQuery approach though.